# How do i copy required values from one JSON object to another with lodash?

Tags: javascript

//I have two

```
var obj1={
 "name":"mayur",
  "age":23
}
var obj2={
    "name":"keyur",
    "age":29,
    "limit":54,
    "surname":"godhani"
}
```

//I know one way

```
var j1 = {name: 'Varun', age: 24};
var j2 = {code: 'NodeJS',name:'mayur', alter: 'C++'}

for (var key in j1) {
    if(j2[key])
        j1[key] = j2[key];
}

console.log(j1);
```

//But i want with lodash or in one line

//--> results should be like

```
var obj1={
    "name":"keyur",
    "age":29
}
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

With Lodash you can use `assign` to add to object and `pick` to pick properties from `obj2` that exists in obj1.

```js
var obj1 = {
  "name": "mayur",
  "age": 23
}

var obj2 = {
  "name": "keyur",
  "age": 29,
  "limit": 54,
  "surname": "godhani"
}

var result = _.assign(obj1, _.pick(obj2, _.keys(obj1)))
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

for one line try this,

```js
var j1 = {name: 'Varun', age: 24};
var j2 = {code: 'NodeJS',name:'mayur', alter: 'C++'}
Object.keys(j1).map(a=>  j1[a] = j2[a] ?  j2[a]: j1[a])
console.log(j1);
```